# Does interface overloaded method order matter?

Tags: typescript

Once I add an overloaded version of a method in an interface, I get errors. However, if I place it before the existing version, I don't. What is the reason? Where can I get more info on this? Is this a matter of the order? Or something else?

```
interface Item {}

interface MyCache {
  // set(key: string, item: Item): void;
  // ^ uncomment the line and it works
  set(record: Record<string, Item[]>): void;
  // set(key: string, item: Item): void;
  // ^ uncomment the line and you get the errors
}

interface State {
  cache: Record<string, Item[]>;
}

function useCache<C>({
  state,
  cache,
}: {
  state: { cache: C };
  cache: { set: (cacheValue: C) => void };
}) {
  const { cache: cacheValue } = state;
  cache.set(cacheValue);
}

function doSomething(state: State, cache: MyCache) {
  useCache({ state, cache });
  // the errors ^ are ^ here
}
```

[Playground (TS v5.3.3)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4F8CwAUEaJLIigLICeAwogBYrZHLIDOEYAFFBAgHsoAEwBcyAEr8hwgDzswUUAHMANGkwBtALoA+AJTiAbgODCA3K2QB6axy7cA1hGriFSkGuTBM49BAxDZBMzS0ICYkJSaHgkZABlMDhIHCsERghxKUEReUUVdX8MHV0wiKIYAFcQBDBgARBkSs56BCZZWl1uFkI2BWSIVTSMofDxHr6kyHHkdLbM5FpkXDC2OaYZzjBxbnWIADU4ABtKhdp9ZABeXWDTYWWyi4nZhoUcWYzxPcOTlFwrjhTCCrD7zAB0W12GR+p30ZSIFWqtXqjWEAniAgwXAYKm4-WmCSB6j24horSYTyszQg5Ig3UBA2JGWWcKIuCAA)

Comment: Yes, TS cares about the order of overloads. See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30369#issuecomment-476402214 When you infer types from overloaded functions the compiler just picks one of the call signatures to use, which tends to be either the first one or the last one... it lacks the ability to figure out the "best" one except when you call it directly.  In your case, it's the generic inference which is just picking the first one, and if you care, you can manually specify it [like this](https://tsplay.dev/wOX4yN).  Shall I write up an answer or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz thank you for the explanation. It seems useful. Sure, go ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript does indeed care about the order of call signatures in an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads).  The obvious dependency is that when you call an overloaded function, the type checker will resolve the call to the first matching call signature, which could result in different behavior if multiple call signatures match:

```
declare function f(x: string | number): string;
declare function f(x: Date | number): Date;
const x = f(123);
//    ^? const x: string;
```

vs

```
declare function f(x: Date | number): Date;
declare function f(x: string | number): string;
const x = f(123);
//    ^? const x: Date;
```

---

But there are other dependencies.  Generally speaking the compiler is only able to perform overload resolution when you call the function directly.  Otherwise, when you infer from overloaded function types, it just picks one of the call signatures.  It can't pick "the best" one, since this would require a much more complex inference algorithm.  As mentioned in [this comment on Microsoft/TypeScript#30369](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30369#issuecomment-476402214):

> In general we can't do overload resolution at the same time as inference and will usually be working with either the first or the last overload, depending on the situation

In your code example, the call to `useCache({ state, cache })` triggers type argument inference for the `C` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter.  And apparently, in this situation, the first overload is selected.  That results in `C` being `string`, and thus an error.  If you change the order of the overloads, this problem goes away.

So that's what's going on.

---

Note that you could keep the call signatures as-is and still call `useCache()` successfully, as long as you don't require the compiler to *infer* `C` for you.  You could just explicitly specify it yourself, like this:

```
useCache<Record<string, Item[]>>({ state, cache }); // okay
```

That works because the compiler is able to *verify* that `cache` has a call signature of the proper type.  It just can't infer it for you.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN7IL4BQBoksiKAsgJ4DCiAFitgcq8gM4RgAUUECAeygATAFzIASvyHCAPOzBRQAcwA0aTAG0AugD4AlOIBuA4MIDcLNpx4BrCFXEKlINcmCZx6CBkPITZpaExODQ8EjIAMpgcJA4VqwIDBDiUoIi8ooq6t4YOrpBRDAAriAIYMACIMjFnHQIjLI0utzMbBwxkKoJyEkNEN144m3WnSk4vcniNPiW7X2Mwxxc4twLEABqcAA2xeM0+sgAvLr+psKzBHiHI4lVChPr4utbuyh4xx2xEHNs6wB0NjWyVee30hQIJTKFSqyGEAkiAgwXHoKm4Cm+4mi33UT2Q1HqjBuPVqEEJEFkaRkmRcbly+RauAxXUm-Xw4OQAHpOcgMHAQMUdtsqBwAA78YAwKhXIgEEBwZHsUXkZAAeQAjPF2sJ+Ns4HxkFDypVqjBuAAPJxZVzIAA+yAFGAARtA-M4VL9WDqEHqDUaYaaLeIACLfO0O4rO10h76ew3cABEcCdCAT+n+YAEAFVReKoHRONxwT0zSAIAB3ZChyBF9PKLgAMWK222AE0IPqi3HBCAHubPmb1QAmADMxfa3PaAD0APy9e5gZCWjq0wryxXKiKqodatje30of0m+PL6soe2Ol1QPxnuP7-WH0rG2Fm5fum0XyNXt3W5Rxs1JimaYZtmubQAWEBdiW3BlpWZ61v89ZgE2Lbtp245-AuS4Dtww5jnGk5sLO869oup6xkQeBAA)